# Why use werkzeug when there is flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am just curious to know as why should we use werkzeug when flask is there. Any specific reason to consider werkzeug over flask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flask and Werkzeug are different things. Flask *contains* Werkzeug as one of the things in it, but also has much more (which might be unwanted).

Flask is a web microframework. Werkzeug is a WSGI middleware.

Comment: Werkzeug is not a WSGI middleware, but a library which contains middlewares and other utilities.